# Splitting two lists and assigning data from one list to values in the other

Tags: python, list, split, assign

and thank you in advance for the help. My problem concerns methods in Python and is as follows.

I have two lists. One list, ***x***, is made up of rows that contain 2 values, *x1* and *x2*, each. The second list, ***data*** is made up of rows that contain 3 values, *x0*, *t*, and *r*, each. I split each row accordingly:

```
for datum in data:
    x0, t, r = data.split()

for item in x:
    x1, x2 = x.split()
```

Values of *x1* and *x2* may be found within values of *x0*. If *x1* corresponds to a value of *x0*, I would like to assign to *x1* the values of *t* and *r* that also correspond to that *x0*. I would like to perform this for each *x2* as well. The end result will be to make some calculation for each pair of *x1* and *x2* values using the values *t* and *r*.

For example: Say we have two lines from ***data*** (*x0*,*t*,*r*):

311 0 2

202 5 13

And we have one line from ***x*** (*x1*,*x2*):

311 202

In the end I'd like to assign the values 0 and 2 to *x1* and 5 and 13 to *x2* so that I can make an arbitrary calculation such as y=r1-r2+t1*t2, where r1 is the *r* value assigned to *x1*, etc. Note that I would like to be able to calculate this for every row in ***x***.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a dictionary from `data` with the key `x0`:

```
dataDictionary = {}
for datum in data:
    x0, t, r = datum.split()
    dataDictionary[x0] = t, r
```

This allows you to look up values from `data` based on `x0`.

Now, when you loop through `x`, you can get those values and do your calculations:

```
for item in x:
    x1, x2 = item.split()
    t1, r1 = dataDictionary[x1]
    t2, r2 = dataDictionary[x2]
    y = r1 - r2 + t1 * t2
    print(y)
```

Comment: Great solution! Just a note for anyone else who has a similar problem, I had to also convert the values of the dictionary to floats in order to perform the calculations.